# Does Google presentations have an API for examining a slide deck?

Tags: google-docs-api

Basically what I want to do is to take an existing slide deck and post it in a forum, where each slide creates a new forum post. This means:

1. Determining how many slides are in the deck.
2. Iterating through each slide and computing the URL for the slide.

Ideally, I'd like to do this on the server rather than on the client.